# Spark streaming whole text files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am learning Spark streaming and I am stuck on probably simple problem. I want to ingest whole text files from a directory. 
Method that is usually mentioned here is wholeTextFile, as opposed to textFile that splits files by lines. However, as far as I found, that method is not available in streaming context.

How to simply achieve similar effect- obtain (filename, whole file content) when streaming?

Scala example with streamingcontext and also sparksession would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Well OP probably don't have the problem anymore since it was in 2017, but I was actually looking something like this and was about to give up when I found a solution to it, Spark 3 will incorporate a format that can be used to achieve this exact thing.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html

My implementation looks similar to this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, TimestampType, LongType, BinaryType}

// This schema is fixed, I don't know if there is an object ready for it, didn't look at it tbh
val schema = StructType(List(
  StructField("path",StringType,false),
  StructField("modificationTime",TimestampType,false),
  StructField("length",LongType,false),
  StructField("content",BinaryType,true)
))

val myDf = spark.readStream 
  .format(...)
  .option("fileFormat", "binaryFile") 
  .schema(schema)
  .load()
```

This approach worked for me, the content object contains the actual content of the file, from there you can simply convert it to whatever final object you need.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched for `wholeTextFile` in a streaming context and could not find anything in the official API.

Although, I encountered the private `WholeTextFileInputFormat` class, which can be used together with a `fileStream` to stream on `(file path, file content)` tuples. However, since this class is private, it can not be used directly. My solution might be a bit hacky:

1. Copy the files [`WholeTextFileInputFormat.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/input/WholeTextFileInputFormat.scala) and [`WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/input/WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala) from the [Apache Spark repository](https://github.com/apache/spark) into your project
2. Adjust the package namespaces accordingly (and also the access modifiers if necessary)
3. Create a stream with a `fileStream` using the `WholeTextFileInputFormat` formatter

Here is an example in Scala, assuming that `ssc` is your `StreamingContext`.

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

val directory = "/the/directory/to/watch"
val stream = ssc.fileStream[Text, Text, WholeTextFileInputFormat](directory)
```